# Open iframe as new clean document/window

Tags: iframe, parent, codesandbox

I am trying to load code from codesandbox into iframe, but it is not going to load.

Probably it is checking if there is parent window opening it from other domain.

Is there any way to hide it and make it think like it was open in new clean window.

I can't  use codesandbox embed, because it is introducing another nested frame, which makes impossible for me to `postMessage` to my code in sandbox.

Comment: Could you give more details as to how you did embed the codesandbox? Did you use the "embed" link? Did you use directly the URL? What kind of sandbox did you create? Using a simple static template I can embed it in jsfiddle and communicate with it just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/t612fq8s/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xcu5mf4h/3/ - maybe it is not loading for some other reason?